# Delete oldest files in directory python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, sorting, delete-file

I'm writing a data logging program (security camera) and I need to delete the oldest file(s) in a folder before the disk is full. There will be thousands of files and it is important that any sorting functions aren't going to tie up resources ideally for more then a couple of seconds. I've read through several ideas and seem to have trouble getting them to work (I'm a bit new to python).

So:
Wondering if os.walk is going be relatively slow with a list of thousands or tens of thousands of files?

I'm very intrigued by Matteo Dell'Amico's suggestion (from another site):

```
min(os.listdir(path), key=os.path.getctime)
max(os.listdir(path), key=os.path.getctime)
```

I keep getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]..... Perhaps someone could help with the syntax needed to fix this? 
Ultimately I'm sure there are multiple ways of doing this but I would prefer the most efficient way on system resources. Thanks so much!

edit: I've tried including at the top:

```
import os
path = "home/pi/Desktop/images/"
```

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns bare names, not fully-qualified ones. It'll work as-is if the path is `.`, or you could add a bit more magic.

Comment: That said, I wouldn't expect it to buy you much over `os.walk()`. You'll save some function call overhead, but that's nothing compared to the cost of I/O.

Answer (score 2):

The code you copied is retrieving bare names from `os.listdir`, and passing them directly to `os.path.getctime`. This doesn't work so well if those names need to be combined with your `path` to work.

A naive modification to what you're already trying (not using any facilities new to Python 3) might look like:

```
min(os.listdir(path), key=lambda p: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path, p)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have log files, you can `rotate` them. `logrotate` has options like `maxage` and the `rotate` that help you delete automatically.

second option is, if you have files, it's just easier to use `find` command withing the terminal(writing a `shell script` and `cronjob`) to do this efficiently.

third option is, using python code:

```
os.path.getmtime(filename)
```

this gives you a `timestamp` of the modification time of `filename`, witch you can pull a `timedelta` on and remove if older than specific time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.
Charles Duffy's Answer didn't work for me and I don't want to write external scripts, so wrote this:

```
oldest_file = min(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path, x))), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
```